# how to built 300px sidebar with html content and inject into current page in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like my Chrome extension to be able to inject a 300px sidebar along with data on the right side of any page when it is activated. I am looking for the best way to build the sidebar along with its HTML content.
I am able to do some small changes to the current page using `contentscript.js` file, but I don't know how to build entire HTML content and display it as a sidebar.

I built the sidebar using the following code in the content script file:

```js
sidebar = $("<div id='sidebar'></div>");

sidebar.css({
    'position': 'fixed',
    'right': '0px',
    'top': '0px',
    'z-index': 9999,
    'width': '290px',
    'height': '100%',
    'background-color': 'blue'  // Confirm it shows up
});

$('body').append(sidebar);
```

Now my question is how to build the HTML content for that sidebar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can inject a Javascript code that create a bar Example this developer "Proper Menubar" creates this. With a click it enable/disable the menubar on the top of Google website.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proper-menubar/egclcjdpndeoioimlbbbmdhcaopnedkp